# Scale down floating divs if container div is smaller

Tags: html, css

I am building a responsive version of my website.

While I'm happy that most floating divs get forced down the screen, there are a few divs that I need to remain next to each other, even if the screen area is smaller than the total width of these divs. In this case, I want to scale them down, so that they fit the screen.

Essentially, here is the layout:

`[___DIV 1___|___DIV 2___|___DIV 3___]`

I want to make sure that when the screen area is small, they don't look like:

```
[___DIV 1___|
___DIV2___|
___DIV3___]
```

but that they look like:

`[div1|div2|div3]`

Each div is `float:left; width:220px;`
The three divs are sitting inside another container div with `width:100%;`

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thank you to all of you who have posted here. Now I am having a really hard time deciding whose answer to choose. What I'll end up doing is keeping `220px;` for the desktop version and then switch to `33%` once the screen width is lower than a certain amount. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You can put all three divs in one container div and only set `float: left` on the container.

```
<div id="container" style="float: left">
    <div id="div1" style="width: 33%">...</div>
    <div id="div2" style="width: 33%">...</div>
    <div id="div3" style="width: 33%">...</div>
</div>
<div id="div4" style="float: left">...</div>
```

Comment: And everything mess up when you add `padding`, `margin` or `border` to the div.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to achieve it is to assign width in percentage in that instance. It should look like :

```
float:left; width:33%;
```

It will solve your issue.

Comment: And everything mess up when you add `padding`, `margin` or `border` to the div.

Comment: so if you are thinking to add all of those properties, you should have knowledge of how to adjust width and height of that particular element. This width is just for reference 
and not a final value.

Comment: And now let's say you want to add 2px border on each side. You can't make it precisely 2px wide because you have to operate on % values.

Comment: so can you provide a better solution in that instance? If you can, then post it as answer. I will surely upvote it. :)

Comment: I posted my approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can change `width:220px;` to  `width:33%`

```
<div id="Main" style="float: left;width:100%;">  
<div id="div1" style="float:left; width:33%;background:yellow;"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="float:left; width:33%;background:blue;"></div>
    <div id="div3" style="float:left; width:33%;background:grey;"></div>
</div>
```

Demo Link : [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5egE/)

Comment: Check my comment on Ganesh Pandhere answer.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers are based on percentage values of the `width` property.

**I have completely another apporach here**. Since you're designing a `response` layout you **should not** rely on percentage values especially when you're trying to fit 3 divs in one row. You should define key resolutions that you're aiming (e.g. smartphone, tablet - landscape/portrait) and design your layout in each of that resolution using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

When using `33%` method you're completely dependent on the device width. You'll never know what the exact width of a div will be so you can't predict how its content will behave.

**EDIT:**
Approach from your comment might look like this

```
div.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:660px) {
    div.column {
        width: 220px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gave me an idea. I will use 33% for widths that are less than the desktop version, and keep 220px; for the desktop one.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `float:left; width:220px;` to something like `float:left; width:40%;`

It should stop them from moving lines.

Comment: A margin will move the div from he same line. If you create jsFiddle it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

change `width:220px;` to `width:33%;`. It will be more flexible. Whenever you scale your web browser, the three div will remain next to each other.

Comment: Check my comment on Ganesh Pandhere answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the width of those divs as a percentage, 33% that would make them scale according to their parent element
here's a jsfiddle, hope it helps!

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}
.third{
    float:left;
    width:32%;
    margin:0.65%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcferrans/MSfmW/

Comment: the key to adding margin or padding is to use relative values, the margin can be added using percentage just make shure it all adds up to 100%, the padding can be added to an element inside the divs

Comment: `<div class="container">
    <div class="third"><p style="padding:1em;">xyz</p></div>
    <div class="third"><p style="padding:1em;">xyz</p></div>
    <div class="third"><p style="padding:1em;">xyz</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>`